# Select Only Text From Inside a div

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<td>
<div>
Text I Want<span class="note-comment">Text I Do Not Want</span>
</div>
</td>
```

This HTML is not mine and therefore cannot be changed. Yes, I know it would be ideal to wrap the "Text I Want" in a span, but its not mine.

Using CSS Selectors, I need to get "Text I Want", without selecting the span node as well. I have tried `:first-child` and was unsuccessful.

If it is absolutely impossible to do with CSS selectors, is there a way to do it it with XPath (Using `text()` I assume)?

Comment: Try to remove the span by class id $('.note-comment').remove() and get the content of div with jquery $('#find_a_way_to_div').html()

Comment: @AdrianP. I am interested in CSS Selectors, not javascript/jquery.

Comment: It's impossible to do in CSS; you cannot write selectors to be dependent upon text content.

Comment: What specific css styling are you trying to apply? That _could_, though may not, make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely impossible to do with CSS selectors. CSS selectors rarely select text (exceptions being the `::first-line` and `::first-letter` pseudo-elements).

Why not select the `<div>` and get its `firstChild`? Anyways, the XPath would be something like `//td/div/text()[1]`.

Comment: Im not interested in javascript ways of doing it, just CSS. I have tried first-line but it did not work.

Comment: @SantaClaus: That’s because it’s not the first line. It’s impossible with CSS. If you’re only interested in CSS, why are you asking about XPath? (Also, that’s not the JavaScript way of doing it, that’s just the DOM way of doing it. I need some context if you don’t find either one helpful.)

Comment: Well, there is a php library that uses CSS selectors to find certain content on a webpage. Thats my context. However, you can use xpath as well if I can figure out how, but thats my problem.

Comment: @SantaClaus: I gave the XPath query too…?

Comment: Also, there should be some way to get `firstChild` from your PHP library. It’s probably even called that if it’s good with names.

Comment: Yeah its called firstChild...I think I will try that. I am surprised that I have not tried that before

Comment: Have you guys looked into the `:not` selector..?

Comment: Just ended up using xpath

Answer (score 0):

impossible in css but it's easy in program.

such as in javascript:

`text.split('<')[0]`